# Interstitial admob время показа (Не более 1 раза в N-количество времени)

Tags: admob

Добрый день! Есть приложение хочу встроить межстраничную рекламу на каждую страницу приложения, но это плохо скажется на опыте использования приложения. Поэтому есть вопрос как реализовать функцию чтобы межстраничная реклама показывалась к примеру не более 1 раза в пять минут?

```html
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

// Prepare the Interstitial Ad
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
// Insert the Ad Unit ID
interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));

interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
// Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // Call displayInterstitial() function
        displayInterstitial();
    }
});

public void displayInterstitial() {
// If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
interstitial.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Timer timer;
int seconds;
static final int PERIOD =60; //раз в минуту
@Override
void onCreate(...) {
  timer = new Timer();
  timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      seconds++;
      if (seconds>=PERIOD) {
        seconds=0;
        displayInterstitial();
      }
    }
  }, 0, 1000);
```

Только нужно подумать и предусмотреть уничтожение объекта timer. Если нужно показывать рекламу из разных активити, то проще написать класс для работы с рекламой, который считает время и определяет необходимо показывать рекламу или нет.